# Google Analytics: how to know the number of clicks on an email link?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in a website. One of the pages has a send-email link as follows:

```
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:someone@example.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'myemail', 'emaillink', 'contactpage');">someone@example.com</a>
```

I would like to know the number of clicks on the above link in GA, but cann't seem to find a way myself.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Analytics, it should appear under *Behavior* > *Events* > *Overview*.

From there, you should be able to navigate the Report and locate the event details, which will contain:

- **Event Category:** myemail
- **Event Action:** emaillink
- **Event Label:** contactpage

The *Total Events* Metric will give you the number of times the Event was recorded.